# Adding a hash to array in perl, adds the same hash multiple times

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I want to add a hash to an array which is constructed from a previous hash value.
Let us say, we have a hash:

`( a=>1, b=>2, c=>3, d=>4)`

I want to transform it to an array of hashes which would contain the following:

```perl
[
    ('key' => 'a', 'value' => 1),
    ('key' => 'b', 'value' => 2),
    ('key' => 'c', 'value' => 3),
    ('key' => 'd', 'value' => 4),
]
```

For doing this, I wrote the below snippet:

```perl
%hash = (a=>1,b=>2, c=>3, d=>4);
@arr = ();
foreach(keys %hash) {
    # Making a hash
    %temp = ('key' => $_, 'value' => $hash{$_});

    # Getting its reference
    $hashref = \%temp;

    # Push the reference of hash in the array
    push( @arr, $hashref);

    # Print it to know its value
    print $_.' '.$hash{$_}."\n";
}

foreach(@arr) {
    # Deref the hash
    %h = %{$_};

    # Print the element
    print 'elem: '.$h{'key'}."\n";

    # Print the reference
    print "Ref: ";
    print ref $_."\n";

    # Print the keys in hash
    print "keys in hash: ".keys %h;
    print "\n";
}
```

But the output contains only four entries of only one reference:

```perl
c 3
a 1
b 2
d 4
elem: d
Ref: keys in hash: 2
elem: d
Ref: keys in hash: 2
elem: d
Ref: keys in hash: 2
elem: d
Ref: keys in hash: 2
```

Why is it adding duplicates?
Any suggestion to add the all the values ?

The code can be tried here: http://ideone.com/OIZiGZ

I have already looked at many answers and then arrived here when it did not work.

Comment: There are a few much shorter ways of writing that `while( my($k,$v) = each %hash ){ push @arr, { key => $k, value => $v }` or `push @arr, { key => $_, value $hash{$_} } for keys %hash` or `for( keys %hash ){ push @arr, { key => $_, value $hash{$_} } }`

Comment: You should always have `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the top of your Perl files until you know exactly why it is recommended. If you had made it so that it works under `use strict;` you would have most likely fixed your code by doing exactly what [ysth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17389/ysth) [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23647505).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding a reference to the same `%temp` hash each time.

Change your code to say:

```
my %temp = ('key' => $_, 'value' => $hash{$_});
```

and each time through the loop `%temp` will be a different hash.

Comment: So does adding 'my' defines it as a new reference ?

Comment: Yes, 'my' limits the scope to the local block (enclosing) block.